# Drawing two edges, one is missing an arrowhead

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm trying to define two parallel arrows as a custom command in my preample as follows:

```
\newcommand{\toto}{\mathrel{%
  \tikz[baseline] \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex) (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);}}
```

The top edge appears first, but only the bottom edge gets an arrowhead. Why? How can I get arrowheads on both edges?

I also tried

```
\newcommand{\toto}{\mathrel{\tikz[baseline]
  \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex);
  \draw[->] (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);}}
```

but it doesn't compile (saying that the first word after the second `draw` is undefined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\toto}{\mathrel{%
  \tikz[baseline] \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) edge[->] (3ex,.96ex) (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);}}

\newcommand{\tototo}{\mathrel{\tikz{[baseline]    %brace after \tikz
  \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex);
   \draw[->] (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);}}}       %brace closing everything

\begin{document}
$\toto$

$\tototo$
\end{document}
```

For the first version, use `edge[->]` for the intermediate arrows. For the second, you are missing braces.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your two definitions don't work for different reasons:

```
\newcommand{\toto}{\mathrel{%
  \tikz[baseline] \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex) (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);}}
```

When you `\draw[->]` an arrow, TikZ only ever adds one arrowhead at the *very end* of the path. Even though the path jumps from one point to another, it's still a single path for purposes of placing arrowheads and the like.

You'll notice the same effect if you use the `decorations` library to place a decoration (like an arrowhead) at, say, 60% of the way along the path: for figuring out where to place the decoration, TikZ effectively lines up the segments end to end (in its own internal memory, not on the page) and calculates 60% of the way along the overall path.

```
\newcommand{\toto}{\mathrel{\tikz[baseline]
  \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex);
  \draw[->] (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);}}
```

This doesn't work because the `\tikz` command only parses commands up until the next semicolon. So your TikZ picture is only this:

```
\tikz[baseline] \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex);
```

Then LaTeX keeps parsing and runs into this:

```
\draw[->] (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);
```

but this is no longer part of the TikZ picture, and `\draw` is not a LaTeX command, so it complains about an undefined command.

You can work around this by putting braces around the argument to `\tikz`:

```
\tikz[baseline] {
  \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex);
  \draw[->] (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);
}
```

This way, both `\draw` commands are combined into a single token which is given as the "argument" to `\tikz`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the implications but the `--` command is actually a line of a path and you decorate the whole path with one arrow in your first example.

The second example should work, but with a correct bracketing (you need to enclose the argument of the \tikz command if you have more than one tikz statement)

```
\newcommand{\toto}{\mathrel{\tikz[baseline] {%
  \draw[->] (0ex,.96ex) -- (3ex,.96ex);
  \draw[->] (0ex,.16ex) -- (3ex,.16ex);}}}
```